# How to see in a "BOX()" in R (shiny) a text of the reactive part

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to see a text from the reactive part in a box() but I don't know why it doesn't show up.

en ui.R:

```
 fluidRow(
 box(title = "Status summary", solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary", width = 4, textOutput("selected_var"))),
```

in server.R :

```
server = function(input, output) {
 output$selected_var <- renderText({"You have selected this"})
}
```

I can see :

[image]

thank you in advance

Comment: If you move `textOutput(...)` to the beginning of the function: `box(textOutput(...), title = ...)`, does that work?

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to know exactly what's wrong without seeing a full reproducible example.  But your basic syntax seems fine.

Here's a full example that shows the `textOutput` rendering correctly in `box()`:

```
# app.R

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(
      title = "Status summary", 
      solidHeader = TRUE, 
      status = "primary", 
      width = 4, 
      textOutput("selected_var")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$selected_var <- renderText("Your input is X")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]